# Laravel Validate and match array variable with Model Collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, eloquent

I have `questions` model in laravel that has a database structure like this:

```
question_id | is_active
------------+-----------
     1      |     Y
     2      |     Y    
     3      |     N
    ...     |    ...
```

I have an input in form of an array that i want to validate with `questions` model, this array will contain key that act as the question_id and the value as the question answer, that looks like this:

```
$QnAs = [
 '1' => '3',
 '2' => '5',
 '4' => '1',
 '6' => '4',
 '7' => '2',
 '8' => '0',
]
```

The validation system will required all the Active (`is_active == 'Y'`) `questions` that  present in the array as `question_id` as the key of array to represent it and the value of each array is 1, 2, 3, or 4.

I can achieve that by looping through every question that active like this:

```
$collections = Questions::where('is_active','Y')->get();
foreach($collections as $collection){
   if(!array_key_exists($collection->question_id,$QnAs)){
     return false; // doesn't find the question id in array key input
   } elseif(!in_array($QnAs[$collection->$question_id],['1','2','3','4'])){
     return false; // input value for this array does not match with required value
   }
}
```

the problem with this code is , when i process 15k++ data  it will take a long time too process because it has to loop through every model collection , is there any other approach that can simplify the code and the process ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code wont work . Beacause return will immediately end the execution of current function. So the checking will be done only with the first value in collections and it will return the result based on the first element in the array $collections.

you can change the code as following :

```
$collections = Questions::where('is_active','Y')->get();

$result = true;
foreach($collections as $collection)
{
   if(!array_key_exists($collection->question_id,$QnAs))
   {
     $result = false; // doesn't find the question id in array key input
   } 
}
return $result;
```

The above code will work
You can research more for greater performance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting all of the active questions,

so the point is to limit the datas,

Firstly, add composite index on `question_id` and `is_active`

```php
$table->index(['question_id', 'is_active']);
```

And try this code:

```php
$QnAs = [
 '1' => '3',
 '2' => '5',
 '4' => '1',
 '6' => '4',
 '7' => '2',
 '8' => '0',
];
// filter elements allowed:
$valid_QnAs = array();
foreach($QnAs as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($v, [1,2,3,4])) {
        $valid_QnAs[$k] = $v;
    }
}

$not_in_active = Questions::where('is_active','Y')
                      ->whereNotIn('question_id', array_keys($valid_QnAs))
                      ->exists();
if ($not_in_active) return false;
```

Comment: thank for the answer, if the $QnAs array value does not contain 1,2,3, or 4 it should return false, no need to insert it in another array